# JOGL program only shows black

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to write a small program that can read in a `.obj` file ("airboat.obj"), and then draw each of it's faces on the screen. Not worrying about any textures from the file.

Reading of the file seems to work fine, but when running, the window only shows black.

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.glu.GLU;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main implements GLEventListener{
    private GLU glu;
    private float angle = 0;
    private float dx = 0f, dy = 0f, dz = 0f;
    private float rotX = 0f, rotY = 0f, rotZ = 0f;

    private ArrayList<int []> f;
    private ArrayList<float []> v;

    private Main(){

        f = new ArrayList<>();
        v = new ArrayList<>();

        loadObj(v, f);
    }

    private void loadObj(ArrayList<float []> V, ArrayList<int []> F){
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("airboat.obj"));
            String line;
            while (br.ready()){
                line = br.readLine();
                int counter = 0;
                if(line.startsWith("v")){
                    String[] lineParts = line.split(" ");
                    float[] vertex = new float[3];
                    for (String number: lineParts) {
                        if (!number.equals("v")){
                            float numint = Float.parseFloat(number);
                            vertex[counter] = numint;
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                    V.add(vertex);

                }else if (line.startsWith("f")){
                    String[] lineParts = line.split(" ");
                    int[] face = new int[lineParts.length-1];
                    for (String number: lineParts){
                        if (!number.equals("f")){
                            int numint = Integer.parseInt(number);
                            face[counter] = numint;
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                    F.add(face);
                }
            }
            br.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        glu = new GLU(); 
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        //gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH); 
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable autoDrawable){
        final GL2 gl  = autoDrawable.getGL().getGL2();

        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);  
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);

        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        draw(gl);
    }

    private void draw(GL2 gl){
        for(int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++){
            final int temp [] = (int []) f.get(i);
            gl.glColor3f(0f,1f,0f);
            if (temp.length == 3){
                gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES);
            }else if (temp.length == 4){
                gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
            }else if (temp.length == 5){
                gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
            }
            for (int j: temp) {
                final float[] temp2 = (float[]) v.get(j-1);
                gl.glVertex3f(temp2[0], temp2[1], temp2[2]);
            }
            gl.glEnd();
            gl.glFlush();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height){
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2(); context
        if (height <= 0) height = 1;  // prevent divide by zero

        final float h = ( float ) width / ( float ) height;
        gl.glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
        gl.glMatrixMode( GL2.GL_PROJECTION );
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        glu.gluPerspective(45.0, h, 45, 100.0);
        gl.glMatrixMode( GL2.GL_MODELVIEW );
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable autoDrawable){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final GLCanvas glCanvas = new GLCanvas();
        Main app = new Main();
        glCanvas.addGLEventListener(app);
        glCanvas.setSize(1280, 720);
        glCanvas.setBackground(Color.white);


        final JFrame aFrame = new JFrame("Airboat Example");
        aFrame.getContentPane().add(glCanvas);
        aFrame.pack();
        aFrame.setVisible(true);

        final FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(glCanvas, 60, true);
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

Any advice on how to debug this sort of thing in the future would be much appreciated too.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried running in debug to check that init and display actually get called?

Comment: Your near plane is suspiciously far from the camera (45, third param to `gluPerspective`).